# how to clone a "template" tab page C#

Tags: c#, clone, tabcontrol, tabpage

So I have a template tab page in my tab control that contains a multi line text box, a button, a progress bar, and a label. I tried searching for cloning the template tab page and adding it to my tab control, but for some reason it crashes at some point about halfway through. Is it cause the tab page has controls inside of it? Should I be cloning each control then add them to a newly created tab page? Is it just easier to create those controls and just set the values at runtime? I figure I must be doing this wrong because I am having a hard to finding information about doing this.

```
private void copyControl(Control sourceControl, Control targetControl)
    {
        // make sure these are the same
        if (sourceControl.GetType() != targetControl.GetType())
        {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect control types");
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceControl.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object newValue = sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceControl, null);

            MethodInfo mi = sourceProperty.GetSetMethod(true);
            if (mi != null)
            {
                sourceProperty.SetValue(targetControl, newValue, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Side question, this seems like this could have name overlap, or does that not matter since each control belongs to a different tab page?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you're going to run into with this solution is that you're copying the control ID(s), which is going to create conflicts in the parent control's "Controls" collection.

Also, when you call "GetProperties()" you should be using the BindingFlags enum to make sure that you grab only Instance, Public properties that have a "Set" accessor.  You can then remove the extra call for "GetSetMethod()".

```
    private void copyControl(Control sourceControl, Control targetControl)
    {
        // make sure these are the same
        if (sourceControl.GetType() != targetControl.GetType())
        {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect control types");
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceControl.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty))
        {
            object newValue = sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceControl, null);
            sourceProperty.SetValue(targetControl, newValue, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm it still seems to fail when it gets to System.Drawing.Size PreferredSize

Comment: What is the error message you get?  Also, can you include an example of a caller to this?  I am assuming that you are creating the "targetControl" in advance of calling this (or you'd be getting a NullReferenceException).  Are you adding the target to the Controls collection of the parent before or after calling this method?